# How do I prevent "format as percent" from changing the number into to a string?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Is there a way for a number to stay as a number and not a string even with the percent sign?

The reason I write a function in a query like:

```
Format(IIf([BDE MTOE CURRENT]=0,0,[PROJECTED OH]/[BDE MTOE CURRENT]),"Percent")
```

is so that I can output a complete report without having to do anything to it.

Microsoft Access (My version is 2007) changes it to a string.

Comment: The answer to your question is "No".  Percent signs are not numeric characters.

Comment: `Format()` returns a variant whose subtype is string.  So it always gives you either Null or a string.

Comment: Yet, in Microsoft Excel if you type 100% in a cell, the number aligns to the right.  And if you look in the formula bar it doesn't say 1.  It says 100%.  Also, if you decide  you want to add 100% + 200% it adds it and returns 300%.  This is what I would like to happen when I output a report to Excel from Access.

Comment: Excel is not Access, and Excel does not use SQL. What Excel can do is irrelevant to your question here, which does not concern Excel. Excel maintains several different pieces of information about an individual cell, such as formatting, value, formula, etc. SQL output does not.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to format the number in the SQL query. There is a formatting option for the values in Access reports:
[image: Access Report - formatting options]

If you are exporting the data to Excel there is a similar option for the Excel cells.

The bottomline is: numbers should stay numbers. That way they are better manageable: you can sort them, you can apply mathematical operations on them

Comment: Thank you.  I am aware of that formatting, but I will not output to an Access report. I will use a vba function called "CopyFromRecordSet."  I use this to create Excel spreadsheets to the customer that are free of any code or links.  This can be very useful.

Comment: Why did you say in your question: "output a complete report without having to do anything"? If it is Excel then use the Excel formatting options for the percent. The bottomline is: numbers should stay numbers. That way theay are better manageable: you can sort them, you can apply mathematical operations on them

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.  I have decided to keep numbers as decimals and will format the spreadsheet columns into percentage from MS Access using VBA.  I kinda hoped I could do it all from SQL.